# how to unset cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I need to figure out how to unset this cookie. Everything I tried so far has failed.

This is how I am currently unsetting it and it doesn't seem to work.

```
setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time() - 7200);
```

This is how I set it:

```
setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time() + 7200);
```

I have this function called `set_session_from_cookie()` that checks if a cookie is set, and if it is set, it starts a new session using the cookie.

The problem is that when I use this on my page I am unable to logout. I assume this is because I am unable to unset the session.

The reason I have this function is if a user wants to be remembered after they end the session, they can restart the session by calling the cookie.

```
function set_session_from_cookie()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$_COOKIE['user_id'];
    }
}
```

Logout:

```
<?php
require'core.php';
session_destroy();

setcookie("user_id", "", time() - 7200);
header('Location:/social_learning/site_pages/starter-template.php');
```

I set my cookie with the following code:

```
if ($rememberme == "on") {
    $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
    setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time() + 7200);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    redirect('home_page.php');
} else {
    if ($rememberme == "") {
        echo 'ok';
        $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'id');
        echo $user_id;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        redirect('home_page.php');
    }
}
```

How can I restart the session using the saved cookie without using the function I created? Since the function seems to be causing the user to no longer be able to logout.

Comment: Is your cookie supposed to be site-wide?

Comment: should it be? how can i tell?

Comment: Don't use relative times for unsetting cookies. That makes the unsetting depend on your user's clock being accurate. Use a time of `1`, which'll catch everyone but those with truly broken clocks who think it's 1970.

Comment: how do i set it to a time of 1?

Comment: This is not secure. Cookies can be easily edited, and in this case someone could log in as any user by editing the cookie. You should use some sort of encryption for the cookie.

Comment: thanks, i know this is unsafe. i will add encryiption once it is working properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that the I needed to set the correct path to unset the cookie since I was unsetting it from a different file that I originally set it in.

I found out which path I needed to use for the unset by looking for the cookie inside my browser cookies, and once I found the cookie inside my browser, the path was listed near the cookie. So I then set the path to the cookie like so:

```
setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time() - 1, "/social_learning/site_pages");
```

The last parameter is the path. And it worked.

My original `setcookie` looks like this:

```
setcookie("user_id", $user_id, time() + 7200, "");
```

Comment: This is the answer. I like how a far more liked answer fails to take account that you did set it to a negative time and it didn't unset. This answer is more appropriate to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

Set the cookie's expiration date to a time in the past (like one second after [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), for example).

`setcookie("yourCookie", "yourValue", 1);`

This will cause the cookie to expire.

`1` is used instead of `0`, because `0` sets the cookie to expire at the end of the session.

Comment: is 1 considered a time  in the past?

Comment: @arboles The time is given in the form of an UNIX timestamp, so yes, 1 was a long time ago :)

Comment: 1 is "1st of january, 19:70 00:00:01 AM"

Comment: More precisely, it is 1 is "1st of january, 19:70 00:00:01 AM UTC". :-)

Comment: in case the cookie's domain is not the default one then you have to pass the domain as fourth parameter of setcookie function too, as in general it's good to always set the third (path) and fourth (domain) parameters

Answer (score 6):

There are few security concerns regarding you code, however to answer your question, to unset a cookie in php, all you need to do is to set expiration time to a time in the past:

```
setcookie("user_id", "", time()-10, "/");
```

"loginform.php" is not a  valid domain, that might be the problem here.

Comment: how can i set the domain, on my local host?

Comment: just put a slash like the one I had in the example "/", that's it, this means that this cookie is available for all your domain.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the php manual for information on setcookie

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

These notes should explain the process:

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

> Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set
>   with. If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all
>   other arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie
>   with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client. This
>   is internally achieved by setting value to 'deleted' and expiration
>   time to one year in past.
>
> Because setting a cookie with a value of FALSE will try to delete the
>   cookie, you should not use boolean values. Instead, use 0 for FALSE
>   and 1 for TRUE.

Comment: i am currently doing this, using the same parameters to delete, as i am to set. and it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

use this code

```
  setcookie("CookieName", "", time()-(60*60*24), "/");
```

works everytime for me in every website

Comment: yes. this means setting time to "yesterday" from the current time.

Answer (score 1):

In php manual, you can delete a cookie by setting a expiration date is in the past:

```
setcookie("key","",time()-3600);
```

In some case, you should provide path and domain for arguments.

In fact, if you assign a cookie with a empty string, it'll also be unset:

```
setcookie("key","");
```

Comment: i know, i am currently doing this method, and it is not working.