# PHP cannot unset cookie

Tags: php, cookies, unset

I have problem in my code.

I have tried to search on the right columns some answers that can help me,
but i didn't found.

This is my inset code:

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['**'])) {
        $set_time_out = 60;
        setcookie("***", "username", time()+60, "admin");
    }
?>
```

now,
my unset code is:

```php
if(isset($_GET['**']) == '***') {
    unset($_COOKIE['***']);
}
```

and when i get in to the "get" link,
nothing happened.

the cookie still exists.

help, please :)

**EDIT**

The login code is..

`<?php
                        if(isset($_POST['*'])) {
                            $set_time_out = 60;
                            setcookie('***', '**', time()+60, 'admin/');
                        }
                    ?>`

And my "logout" code is :

`

```php
if(!$_COOKIE['***']) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=../login.php\">";
}

if(isset($_GET['**']) == '******') {
    setcookie('***', '', time()-60, 'admin/');
}
```

?>`

Comment: Already answered, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10526967/1409082)

Comment: no, it is not already answered.....

Answer (score 5):

Set its expire time to backward ,it will unset the cookie

```
setcookie('cookiename', '', time()-3600);
```

Comment: the solution isnt work..

Comment: @user2035053 For destroying cookie it's the best way. And its working for all..:)

Comment: its not work.............

Comment: i change cookie to: setcookie("***", "username", time()+60, "admin"); ,coz the cookie goes to admin directory, but still - isnt work.

Comment: It is not +60 but -3600. Look more carefully.

Comment: no, thats the login act..

Comment: the one thing that everybody here has ignored and should have brought up is the fact that cookies have a domain and path ad well. if setcookie('cookiename','',1); doesn't work, you need to make sure the path and domain are correct too. setcookie('cookiename','',1,cookie_path, cookie_domain)

Answer (score 3):

set cookie in the past... like:

```
setcookie ("***", "username", time() - 3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

to [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) cookie, you need to set your expire time to the past, like.

```
setcookie('your_cookie_name', '', time()-3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie always set its time in negative from the current time().

```
setcookie('nameofcookie', '', time()-3600);
```

This code sets your cookie persist time to negative so it automatically deletes.

Answer (score 0):

// set the expiration date to one hour ago

```
 setcookie("cookiename","", time()-3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("cookie name", "", time()-3600);
```