# Codeigniter - logout link doesn't works - session and cookies not destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, logout

i made a simple logout url with the controller and it looks like this:

```
 class Auth extends MX_Controller{
        function logout(){
          $this->session->sess_destroy();
          $this->bootstrap->unsetUserCookie();

          redirect(base_url(),'',301);
        }
    }
```

then

```
class Bootstrap{

function unsetUserCookie(){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->input->set_cookie(
      array(
        'name'=>'remember_me',
        'value'=>'',
        'expire'=>''
        ));
    $CI->input->set_cookie(
      array(
        'name'=>'remember_me_n',
        'value'=>'',
        'expire'=>''
        ));
    $CI->input->set_cookie(
      array(
        'name'=>'duser_lang',
        'value'=>'',
        'expire'=>''
        ));
    $CI->input->set_cookie(
      array(
        'name'=>'duser_country',
        'value'=>'',
        'expire'=>''
        ));
  }
}
```

i'm using the session DB these are the config params i'm using:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'sess_id';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0; //24hours -> 8640
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3000000000;
```

then i created a simple session library and don't know if this can block anything but i guess no cause i receive no errors at all:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

/*We encode/decode all session data in base64 to avoid problems with multybityes data*/
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

      function set_userdata($data, $singleVar = NULL) {

          if(is_array($data)){
            $newValues = array();
            foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {

                $newValues[$key] = base64_encode($value);
            }

              parent::set_userdata($newValues);
          }
        else{
            if(is_array($singleVar)){
            $newValues = array();
            foreach ($singleVar as $key=>$value) {

            $newValues[$key] = base64_encode($value);
            }
            //Encode $singleVar 
            parent::set_userdata($data, $newValues);
            }else{
                 parent::set_userdata($data, base64_encode($singleVar)); 
            }
        }
    }
      function set_flashdata($data, $singleVar = NULL) {

          if(is_array($data)){
            $newValues = array();
            foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {

                $newValues[$key] = base64_encode($value);
            }

              parent::set_flashdata($newValues);
          }
        else{
            if(is_array($singleVar)){
            $newValues = array();
            foreach ($singleVar as $key=>$value) {

            $newValues[$key] = base64_encode($value);
            }
            //Encode $singleVar 
            parent::set_flashdata($data, $newValues);
            }else{
                 parent::set_flashdata($data, base64_encode($singleVar)); 
            }
        }
    }
     public function userdata($item) {

         $data = parent::userdata($item);
         if(is_array($data)){
            $newData = array();
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $newData[$key] = base64_decode($value);
            }
            return $newData;
         }else{
        //Decode $data
        return base64_decode($data);
    }
}



}



/* End of file  */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/ */

?>
```

the url is so simple,it just had to delete session and cookies, but the session and the cookies  seems not to be deleted cause after launching the logout url i'm still logged.

Any clue please?

Comment: have you checked if the session(Cookie) is really destroyd and if its therefore a problem of you loggedin check function?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526967/how-to-unset-cookie-in-php) question / answer on removing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

you code is fasle :

```
class Auth extends MX_Controller{
        function logout(){
          $this->session->sess_destroy();
          $this->bootstrap->unsetUserCookie();

          redirect(base_url(),'',301);
        }
    }
```

this extends is MY_Controller,

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller{
```

Comment: nope i'm using th HMVC so each controller has to extend MX_Controller actually :)

Comment: Yes that not support.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was the cache problem. It could be solved by adding the below header code inside the constuctor function or any other function where the login code is related.

`header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");`