# How to remove persistent cookie from Text size module in drupal 7

Tags: session, cookies, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am developing a site in Drupal 7. I am doing the security audit for the same. in a security audit, I am getting the issue for Persistent Cookie. when I check the cookies for my site. there is one cookie name **"text size"** which is persistent. but I want session cookie only. how do I achieve this please help?

Thanks in advance.

[Screen shot of cookie view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEMFH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 day's research on it and the help of the Answer provided by Mr. Vishwanath Polaki. Finlay I have reached at objective.

i have edited textsize.module file.

**setcookie("textsize", $textsize_normal, time()+$textsize_cookie_expires, $textsize_cookie_domain, "");**

in the above statement i only update the **time()+$textsize_cookie_expires** with value **0**.

Before change the cookie [cookie-screen-before-updation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4zGn.png)

After change the cookie  [cookie-screen-after-updation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX5Tf.png)

expiration of the cookie is change from **specific time** to **At end of session**

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the cookie in your module hooks e.g hook_boot or hook_init in your custom module.

There you can just write:

```
setcookie("text size", "{yourValue}", 1);
```

For more information refer below:

[how to unset cookie in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526967/how-to-unset-cookie-in-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: You are welcome. If you had issues in implementing you can just add comment so that I could provide more info on module creation and setting time for cookie.